# Backbone js re-rendering leaves the view eventless

Tags: backbone.js

All,

I am buidling an app with Backbone JS and as per my methodology am firing a request to the server to update my local storage on each hashchange if the first model lookup is too old.

So what I am dealing with is this.

```
(hashchange) -> 
  fetch model -> 
    (if model expired [eg: grabbed from LS], fetch again in background)
    render
```

In the view I have bound a change event to the model pointing to render so that when that second request comes back the page just re-renders.

To you gents and ladies, I ask why does when the first page gets loaded all the events work (click and such) but if the view re-renders, they do not anymore?

Some code to help you out for the views, there is a nested view with a nested request:

```
class ShowView extends Backbone.View
  template: +some template+
  initialize: ->
    this.render()
    @model.bind('change', this.render)

  render: ->
    $(@el).html(this.template(@model.toJSON())
    items = new ItemCollection
    @model.set(items: items, {silent: true})
    @$items = new ItemsView(collection: items, el: @$('#posts'))
    items.fetch()
    +displayPage @el+
    @

 class ItemsView extends Backbone.View
   template: +some template+
   initialize: ->
     @collection.bind('reset', this.render)

   render: =>
     @collection.each( (model) -> new ItemView(model: model))
     @
```

... one more I swear ...

```
 class ItemView extends Backbone.View
   template: +some template+
   events:
     'click .inner': 'showItem'

   initialize: ->
     this.render()

   render: ->
     $(@el).html(this.template(@model.toJSON()))
     @
```

All of this has been generalized, but the concept is the same.

When that change event fires and everything gets refreshed and I click on a .inner, nothing happens.

Suggestions?  I have tried to unbind and remove the views before the new render has taken place, also I have tried to delegateEvents on the end of all the render methods.

Thanks

--UPDATE--

The ItemView Template:

```
<a class="inner">
  <img src="item/image.gif" />
  <h3><%= title %></h3>
  <p><%= description %></p>
</a>
```

The showItem method in ItemView is just a simple redirect to the actual item:

```
showItem: ->
  window.location.hash = "#/posts/#{@model.id}/show"
```

I forgot to mention that ItemView's tagName is 'li' and ItemsView tagName is 'ul', so all this does is make a list on the page.

Comment: what does the template for ItemView look like? also, what does the `showItem` method of ItemView look like?

Comment: I'm working on a jsFiddle for it right now but the post has been updated.

Comment: I think it is related to [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7663800/).  This is because the rerender in the view refreshes the listview thus losing events? It is only a theory, when I get a little more help with the other ticket I will compile my sources and try again.

Answer (score 1):

Put this code in your render function:

```
this.delegateEvents();
```

Read the explanation [here](http://backbonejs.org/#View-delegateEvents).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so here is what I did to solve this annoying bug:

The Backbone.View comes with the unbind method from Backbone.Events.

So what I do in essence is keep track of every view that I create and when I create a different view or rerender the samve view, I unbind all previous views from the DOM.

In the case of my example above, here is the code that works for me:

```
class ShowView extends Backbone.View
  template: +some template+
  initialize: ->
    this.render()
    @model.bind('change', this.render)

  render: ->
    $(@el).html(this.template(@model.toJSON())
    items = new ItemCollection
    @model.set(items: items, {silent: true})
    @$items.unbind() if @$items             # for the subview events
    items.fetch()
    @$items = new ItemsView(collection: items, el: @$('#posts'))
    this.delegateEvents()                   # For the current view events
    +displayPage @el+
    @

    unbind: ->
      super
      @$items.unbind() if @$items

class ItemsView extends Backbone.View
   template: +some template+
   initialize: ->
     @collection.bind('reset', this.render)

   render: =>
     @collection.each( (model) -> new ItemView(model: model))
     this.delegateEvents()                 # For the current view events
     @
```

Cheers,
 Cbarton